# Accessing indices in an array where the elements value difference occurs

Tags: python

I have a one  dimensional list like :

```py
val=np.array([1,1,0,0,1,1,0,4,0,0,1])
```

My requirement is to access the indices, where the difference between element is 1(like the transition occurs from 1 to 0 and 0 to 1 in that point the value difference is -1,1 respectively).

I tried with this function.  some how,I am able to get the desired out put.

```py
val=np.array([1,1,0,0,1,1,0,4,0,0,1])

result_1 = [(i, i + 1)for i in np.where(np.diff(val) ==1 )[0]]
result_2=[(i, i + 1)for i in np.where(np.diff(val) ==-1)[0]]
```

Received output:

```py
[(3, 4), (9, 10)]
[(1, 2), (5, 6)]
```

Again,I tried again with and function

```py
result_1 = [(i, i + 1)for i in np.where(np.diff((val) ==1 & (val) ==1 ))[0]]
```

I received an error like this

```
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() 
or a.all()
```

Expected output:

```py
[(1,2),(3, 4),(5,6) (9, 10)]
```

Comment: Why does the expected output contain `(1, 2)` when both `val[0][1]` and `val[0][2]` are equal to 1?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Compare against the [absolute value](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absolute_value) (using [`numpy.abs`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.absolute.html)) to combine both results:

```
import numpy as np

val = np.array([1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 4, 0, 0, 1])

result = [(i, i + 1) for i in np.where(np.abs(np.diff(val)) == 1)[0]]
print(result)
```

**Output**

```
[(1, 2), (3, 4), (5, 6), (9, 10)]
```